# Event Grid system topic logs not visible

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Under Event Grid system topic I don't see "Logs" option to view the diagnostic settings logs. How do I view it using Log Analytics workspace ? The tables are not seen under Log Analytics workspace as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To view the logs of Azure Event Grid System Topic, you have to enable the diagnostic settings under monitoring section of the Azure Event Grid System Topic Menu Page.

[image]

You have to select the type of logs required and where to send those logs for accessibility.

> I don't see "Logs" option to view the diagnostic settings logs.

You can View the logs in the Storage account that you sent from the diagnostic setting and one of the sample examples is available in below MS Document.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/enable-diagnostic-logs-topic#enable-diagnostic-logs-for-event-grid-system-topics) for more information on the Azure Event Grid System Topic Logs Configuration.

Comment: "Logs" option is to view the logs after the diagnostic settings are enabled and logs are forwarded to Log Analytics workspace. I'm not seeing the logs under analytics workspace.

Comment: What is the query you have used to see the logs under the workspace?

Comment: I don't see the tables under the workspace to run any query.